# Проблема загрузки Rails на Heroku а именно с файлом index.erb

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, erb

У меня вот такая проблема:

Когда загружаю проект на Rails в Heroku, а именно с файлом index.html, он у меня находится в каталоге /public - Heroku нормально видит, а когда загружаю проект с файлом index.erb то показывает такую ошибку:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

И такая ошибка бывает еще тогда, когда часто пользуешься командой `heroku create` создается куча других проектов, что приходится их постоянно удалять, что не выскакивала такая ошибка.
Приведите пожалуйста код, как правильно переименовывать проект на Heroku.

Comment: А зачем у вас index.erb находится в public?

Comment: Прекрасная Василиса, вы лучше объяснили как правильно сделать, хотя я решения проблемы нашел, теперь меня волнует другое, как правильно переменовать проект на Heroku, чтоб потом не выскакивали ошибки.

Comment: Для того, чтобы рассказать вам, как сделать правильно, мне бы понять, что вы пытаетесь сделать и зачем. Для рельсового проекта очень нехарактерно складывание чего-либо в public, вот я и уточняю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы переименовать проект, выполните из директории вашего проекта команду, в этом случае гитовская ссылка обновится автоматически

```
heroku apps:rename newname
```

либо из любого другого местоположения, в этом случае надо будет заново её создать

```
heroku apps:rename newname --app oldname
# это уже в вашем проекте
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

Подробнее [тут](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps)

Comment: А как избавится от проблемы, когда я обновляю проект на Heroku, а обновляю я его командой heroku create и у меня создаются новые сайты и потом показывает ошибку The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information. как от такой проблемы избавится ?

Comment: @АлисГрусть Что вы подразумеваете под обновлением? `heroku create` служит для создания проекта. И в каком месте вы получаете ошибку? При попытке перейти по url со старым именем проекта? Ну так всё логично, его больше не существует, там пусто

Comment: @АлисГрусть, если вы расскажете, чего вы хотите добиться, и зачем вам постоянное переименование проектов, то помочь будет гораздо проще

Comment: Мне не нужно постоянное переменования, я хочу спокойно обновлять один и тот же проект, можно обновлять проект тот-же самый но без heroku create

Comment: @АлисГрусть, сдаётся мне, вы не тем инструментом пользуетесь. Правильный способ работы с heroku - закоммитили локально, выполнили `git push origin master && git push heroku master`, либо настроили на хероку автодеплой мастера (или любой другой ветки) из гитхаба. Почитайте внимательно [тут](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Comment: Спасибо помогло